# Access control and user information in main db

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express, user-accounts

We have one database to carry out our operations. The application is fetching the records from Oracle database and MSSQL is processing those records, tally them with biometric machine data and then storing this information into MSSQL. On dev machine, I have sql-express 2008 installed whereas on production server they have Sql Server 2005 installed. I need to store the User accounts with their authentication details, roles and also need to make relationship between users with other entities.

Is there a way to map the User table to the EF model so we can associate it with other entities?

<del>- Can we make ASPNETDB.MDF as a main database for all the entities?</del>

<del>- Can we migrate the User roles, User profiles, Membership information and the corresponding stored procedure from ASPNETDB into the other db?</del>

**EDIT :**

I found this article http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs which helps me figure out the way to equip any SQL-server database with membership, user, profile tables and stored procedure using [**aspnet_regsql**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229862%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) utility.

**Update :**

In AccountsModel, I created a class AccountDetails.

```
public class AccountDetails : ProfileBase
{
    public int TerminalId { get; set; }
}
```

& in TerminalModel:

```
public ICollection<AccountDetails> UserProfiles { get; set; }
```

Actually, I just need an additional attribute (FK) TerminalId in Users table. But the documentation suggest to append the attribute in User table, we need to use profile. So with the above code how to get MembershipUser collection from UserProfiles? Should I have to loop through the collection or is there any sleek way to perform the operation... something like:

```
public static ICollection<MembershipUser> GetUsersFromProfiles(ICollection<AccountDetails> mProfiles)
{
     /* it is not accepting the Membership.GetAllUsers()... 
        Error: "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source
        type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection'.  'Where' not found.
        Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'm'.*/
     return (from m in Membership.GetAllUsers()
             where m.UserName = mProfiles.SelectMany(profile=>profile.UserName)
             select m);
}
```

When I try to save a record in ConvertToTerminalArray method:

```
public class Terminal
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Terminal Name")]
    public string TerminalName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public static Terminal[] ConvertToTerminalArray(string terminalName = "Tango 1")
    {
        ApplicationServices db = new ApplicationServices();
     //   var dsd=new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationServices>();
     //   dsd.InitializeDatabase(db);
        Terminal [] terminal = new Terminal[1];
        terminal[0] = new Terminal();
        terminal[0].TerminalName=terminalName;
        terminal[0].Location = "South West Coast";
        db.Terminals.Add(terminal[0]);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return terminal;

    }
```

}

It gives me this error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Terminals'.  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object
>   name 'dbo.Terminals'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 34:             terminal[0].Location = "South West Coast"; Line
>   35:             db.Terminals.Add(terminal[0]); Line 36:
>   db.SaveChanges(); Line 37:  Line 38:             return terminal;

The ApplicationServices (context) looks like:

```
public class ApplicationServices : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationServices()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationServices>());
    }

    public DbSet<Terminal> Terminals { get; set; }
}
```

Please help.